# How can we know the JSON structure of a Facebook graph api field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I am requesting a JSON string for specific field using Graph API, how can I know the structure of the JSON string ahead of time? What if I want to request a field something like "user_interests" - how do I know its structure inside the JSON?

It may be possible to first print it on screen, but I do not know who in my friend's list has first of all added information for this field.

Thanks
Abhishek S

Comment: I don't get the question, if you want to know the structure of JSON just launch the call using facebook Graph API Explorer

Comment: What I am saying here is, education_history element in the JSON String has a particular structure. If I haven't exposed my education_history, then I do not know what are the sub-parts of this JSON element, and how should I parse it. Is there a way to know how the sub-parts of JSON elements are placed in advance?

Comment: Which language are you using? PHP, Java, Javascript.... ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest way is to do a query with [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and have a look at the response.
Graph Explorer also allows you to toggle permissions. It can be used with FQL calls as well, like so (using a simple example):

```
graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

You may also find [FBDevWiki](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Main_Page) useful. It outlines the return values for each Graph object and FQL table. For example, see the [user](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Graph%3aUser) Graph object.

Comment: What I am saying here is, education_history element in the JSON String has a particular structure. If I haven't exposed my education_history, then I do not know what are the sub-parts of this JSON element, and how should I parse it. Is there a way to know how the sub-parts of JSON elements are placed in advance?

Comment: If you want to see the structure of a particular response e.g. education history, either add education history to your test account and request it in Graph Explorer or view the response at a breakpoint in your IDE. FBDevWiki's summaries may also be helpful - see my edited answer.

Comment: What if the field "education history" doesn't contain any value at all? In that case, I won't be seeing the fields inside this JSON Object right?

Answer (score 0):

If the language you are using is Java I strongly recommend you to use a library that help you out *"wrapping"* facebook Graph API.
Personally I'm working right now with [REST FB](http://restfb.com/) , and it's a good library, except for some marginal missing features (like the possibility to easily create mock up tests).

One of the main advantage of using a library like this one is that you don't have to manually parse facebook JSON responses but it's already encapsulated in a java object (then you simply access to a field in the classic java bean way e.g.: myPost.getMessage() ).

Check the documentation for more specific examples, I think this is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is question about JSON and not about facebook.
Depends with what programming language you work with, you need to check what are the fields/keys that exist in the JSON from the root to the sub-parts.

For example in iOS(iphone), the json is converted to NSArray/NSDictionary and I check if key/field exist (not nil).

this is about your question  " how do I know its structure inside the JSON?"